# Power BI failed to load tables

Tags: mongodb, powerbi, powerquery

I’ve been getting this error when trying to apply my tables from power query to power bi. I imported tables from mongo DB and Excel

PS: I have done this before without error…. I’m trying to do it again and I’m getting this error. Please help

```
Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'OLE DB or ODBC error: (DataSource, Error] ODBC: ERROR [HY000] [MySQLIODBC 14(W) Driver][mysald-5,7.12 mongosqld v2.14.4]This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet. OLE DB or ODBC error: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040E4E. OLE DB or ODBC error:
Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040E4E. OLE DB or ODBC error:
Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040F4E. OLE DB or ODBC error
Exception from RESULT: 0x80040E4E
```

I want to apply my tables successfully into power BI

Answer (score 2):

You create a data model in power BI and after update data, you need to check if table's primary key is unique. If it is duplicated, you can get this error.

If that is not a solution for you, check it out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/get-data/9-import-errors

[image]

Comment: That's not the same error.

Comment: Error code is the same, but I didn't put error's screen shot in the comment.

Comment: It's fairly obvious that it's not the same error. Yours is a duplicate value error, the OP is an ODBC error about an unsupported command.

Comment: At the beginning of the error it said "OLE DB or ODBC error: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040E4E". Just because this answer doesn't help you doesn't mean it won't help someone else. I don't understand what your purpose is.

Comment: Did you read the error message? It's not a duplicate value problem. My guess is that an unsupported character was added in the underlying data.